# Node js req getting updated in case of concurrent request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am facing some kind of issue in the case of concurrent request handling using express. I am using some encrypted value in every request header and want to set it to some global variable from middleware after decrypting it and want to use it in all the controllers, utils across the project.

```
var app = express();

app.use("/test_test",Controller.testtest);

exports.testtest = async function (req, res) {
    globalcons.vals.ssip = req.body.ssip;
    var usr = req.body.usr;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 8000));
    let response = {};
    response['status'] = 'success';
    response['ssip'] = globalcons.vals.ssip;   // this is changing
    response['usr'] = usr;  //this is not
    return apiResponse.successApiResponse(res, response);

}
```

[image: Here is the problem screenshot]

Comment: When using a global variable, isn't this the expected result?

Comment: no, I want to see the same ssip in resp as it present in req body... the resp ssip value is updating with some other request ssip value while I am holding the code for 8 sec to make some other request.

Comment: If by design the value is global and changed by every request, then this is the expected result. Either change the design or consider returning `req.body.ssip` instead.

Comment: Are you really sure that express works with an `async` middleware function ? The [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) don't mention it. You may want to [wrap](https://github.com/codebysd/node-asyncback) middleware functions to be able to use async.